# Use annotation @Index hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dictionary, indexing

I would like to add index(@Index) but I can't. When I add @Index on the other property(displayName) it works and create this index on DB but when I add it on "contacts" property it does not work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_PARTY")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PARTY_TYPE", 
discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQ_PARTY", 
  allocationSize = 1)
public  abstract class Party extends BaseEntity {
.....
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARTY_ID", nullable = false,unique = true)
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
**@Index(name = "IDX_CONTACTS")**
public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}
**@Index(name="IDX_NAME)**
@Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME")
public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `@IndexColumn` instead of `@Index` for `getContacts()` as you are using a collection return type.

You can also use the `@OrderedColumn` annotation which is compatible with the JPA API as specified here [link](http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch08s05.html). I don't know if your `Contact` object is embeddable so I would advise against using the `@ElementCollection` as it will be mapped to a collection table.

Comment: @OrderedColumn don't work for me. Contacts is just a OneToMany relation and it is not embedded.